# Can I change the client button on Discord.js without affecting all users?

Tags: discord, discord.js

Is it possible to change the button only for the client, and not for all users?
for example, change the color of the user's button from blue to red or change the button text for a specific user

interaction.update change the button for all users

Comment: Only if the message is ephemeral or private to a specific user. If it's a universal message that everyone can see, no